# Emberjs - how do I set a property on an itemController from a route?

Tags: ember.js

I have an ArrayController that uses associated itemControllers to track a checked property on the set of models (i.e. whether or not their checkbox is checked).

This part is currently working fine. When I come back to the route, I need to use some information off of the user model to "remember" which were checked.

How can I set the checked property on the specific itemController's? I can get references to the individual models that need "checking", but model.set('checked', true) doesn't seem to get picked up by the itemController in that scenario.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: which checkbox did you use??... Ember.Select or any thing else???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your array controller, iterate `this` and that will give you each individual `itemController`.  Here's the basic concept

```
App.FooController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  someFunc: function(){
    this.forEach(function(item){
      item.set('checked', item.get('model.wasChecked'))
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. The issue was that I was trying to do everything on the *content* rather than the controller. i.e. `this.get('content').forEach( function....`.